# SWIG wrap boost::none_t in Java

Tags: swig

I have following c++ functions for which i am making Java wrapper

```
void label(const std::string &label) {   // wrapper correctly built
   ...
}

void label(const boost::none_t t) {    // generating SWIGTYPE_p_boost__none_t
    ...
}
```

How can i correctly wrap boost::none_t in Java. I m new to SWIG. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on quite what this function actually does you probably want something like:

```cpp
%{
#include <boost/none.hpp>
%}

%typemap(in,numinputs=0) boost::none_t %{
    $1 = boost::none;
%}

void label(const boost::none_t t);
```

Which then generates the following Java:

```java
public static void label()
```

The argument is omitted in Java and automatically filled out with `boost::none` via an assignment before the function gets called.